# Backbone's success callback called before jquery's ajaxSuccess

Tags: jquery, ajax, backbone.js, callback

I would like to make sure that jQuery's ajaxSuccess callback is called before Backbone's success, which is not the case in my experience. I would like this

```
someModel.fetch({ success: function() {
  console.log('2');
} });

$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(event, xhr, ajaxOptions) {
  console.log('1');
});
```

to log `1, 2` and not `2, 1`. The reason being that I am using `ajaxSuccess` to pre-filter the response and saving data that are needed in Backbone's callback

Comment: Asynchrounous vs Synchronous.

Comment: Backbone being built on top of jquery I was wondering if there'd be a way to overwrite some of the callback mechanism. Plus both seem to be async mechanisms...

Comment: If .fetch is resulting in a jQuery ajax request, what you are seeing is the expected behavior of jQuery global events. global events always happen ***after*** events defined for the specific request. I think you're using the wrong tool for the job, jQuery has other ways of hooking into and manipulating the results of ajax requests. converters for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you have shown not necessarily mean Backbone call is earlier than ajax success callback. it is probably ajax success is called first. then immediately the backbone callback is also invoked. then it depends on which one is faster, the faster one will log first.

it means backbone callback is not called after ajaxsuccess is finished.

in your case, you want to preprocess ajax stuff before passing into model. this is very common. in fact, Backbone does have a native support of this. check Backbone.parse method. it is by default empty, but you can certainly modify it to change the response.

Comment: Cool I think it is as good as it can get! (I was hoping to have a broader solution that would also intercept non backbone ajax callback) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your fetch success, try putting the code you want executed in a setTimeout of 0.

This should execute it immediately after other things have run.

Note, I'd prefer to use parse as evilsanta suggested. This is more about what you can do than necessarily should do.